# Asynchronous catalog with paging and partial views

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I'm trying out .net core with mvc in a personal project, the latest functionality I've added was a project catalog, primarily ajax based, it's displaying a list of projects fetched from the database using web api in a catalogish order and interface.

---

### Web API

Starting with the infrastructure layer, I decided to have 2 classes, obviously one api controller and one http wrapper service, to allow easier usage of the web api. For this part of the project there are 2 necessary services - `ProjectService` and `ProjectFavoritesService`, the first one contains crud operations for the project objects and project favorites is a junction table for User and Project and allows for projects to be favorited by a user.

**IProjectsService**

```
public interface IProjectsService
{
    Task<int> AddProject(ProjectsDTO dto);
    Task<int> ModifyProject(ProjectsDTO dto);
    Task RemoveProject(int id);
    Task<ProjectsDTO> GetProject(int id);
    Task<List<ProjectsDTO>> GetProjects();
}
```

**ProjectsController**

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ProjectsController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly DexContext _context;
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;

    public ProjectsController(DexContext context, IMapper mapper)
    {
        _context = context;
        _mapper = mapper;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("AddProject")]
    public IActionResult AddProject(ProjectsDTO dto)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                var entity = _mapper.Map<Projects>(dto);
                _context.Projects.Add(entity);
                _context.SaveChanges();

                if (entity.Id > 0)
                {
                    return Ok(entity.Id);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }
        }

        return BadRequest();
    }

    [HttpPut]
    [Route("ModifyProject")]
    public IActionResult ModifyProject(ProjectsDTO dto)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                var entity = _context.Projects.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == dto.Id);
                if (entity == null)
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }

                _mapper.Map(dto, entity);
                _context.SaveChanges();

                return Ok(entity.Id);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }
        }

        return BadRequest();
    }

    [HttpDelete]
    [Route("RemoveProject")]
    public IActionResult RemoveProject(int? id)
    {
        if(id == null) { return BadRequest(); }

        var entity = _context.Projects.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == id);
        if (entity == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        try
        {
            _context.Projects.Remove(entity);
            _context.SaveChanges();
            return Ok();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("GetProject")]
    public IActionResult GetProject(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null) { return BadRequest(); }

        try
        {
            var project = _context.Projects.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == id);
            if (project == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return Ok(_mapper.Map<ProjectsDTO>(project));
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("GetProjects")]
    public IActionResult GetProjects()
    {
        if (_context == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        try
        {
            return Ok(_context.Projects.Select(p => _mapper.Map<ProjectsDTO>(p)));
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }
    }
}
```

**ProjectFavoritesController**

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ProjectFavoritesController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly DexContext _context;
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;

    public ProjectFavoritesController(DexContext context, IMapper mapper)
    {
        _context = context;
        _mapper = mapper;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("AddFavorite")]
    public IActionResult AddFavorite(ProjectFavoritesDTO dto)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                var entity = _mapper.Map<ProjectFavorites>(dto);
                _context.ProjectFavorites.Add(entity);
                _context.SaveChanges();

                return Ok();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }
        }

        return BadRequest();
    }

    [HttpDelete]
    [Route("RemoveFavorite")]
    public IActionResult RemoveFavorite(ProjectFavoritesDTO dto)
    {
        if (dto == null) { return BadRequest(); }

        try
        {
            var entity = _context.ProjectFavorites.SingleOrDefault(p => p.ProjectId == dto.ProjectId && p.UserId == dto.UserId);
            if (entity == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            _context.ProjectFavorites.Remove(entity);
            _context.SaveChanges();
            return Ok();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("GetFavoritesByUser")]
    public IActionResult GetFavoritesByUser(string userId)
    {
        if (_context == null || userId == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        try
        {
            return Ok(_context.ProjectFavorites.Where(p => p.UserId == userId)
                .Select(p => _mapper.Map<ProjectFavoritesDTO>(p)));
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("GetFavoritesByProject")]
    public IActionResult GetFavoritesByProject(int? projectId)
    {
        if (_context == null || projectId == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        try
        {
            return Ok(_context.ProjectFavorites.Where(p => p.ProjectId == projectId)
                .Select(p => _mapper.Map<ProjectFavoritesDTO>(p)));
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }
    }
}
```

### Web API Client Services

**ProjectsService**

```
public class ProjectsService : IProjectsService
{
    private readonly string _host;
    private const string ControllerAddress = "api/projects/";

    public ProjectsService(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        if (configuration == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(configuration)); }

        _host = configuration.GetSection("Data").GetSection("Host").Value;
    }

    public async Task<int> AddProject(ProjectsDTO dto)
    {
        using var client = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(_host + ControllerAddress) };

        var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(nameof(ProjectsController.AddProject), dto);

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var message = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            if (int.TryParse(message, out var id))
            {
                return id;
            }
        }

        return -1;
    }

    public async Task<int> ModifyProject(ProjectsDTO dto)
    {
        using var client = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(_host + ControllerAddress) };

        var response = await client.PutAsJsonAsync(nameof(ProjectsController.ModifyProject), dto);

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var message = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            if (int.TryParse(message, out var id))
            {
                return id;
            }
        }

        return -1;
    }

    public async Task RemoveProject(int id)
    {
        using var client = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(_host + ControllerAddress) };

        await client.DeleteAsync($"{nameof(ProjectsController.RemoveProject)}?id={id}");
    }

    public async Task<ProjectsDTO> GetProject(int id)
    {
        using var client = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(_host + ControllerAddress) };

        var response = await client.GetAsync($"{nameof(ProjectsController.GetProject)}?id={id}");

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var message = await response.Content.ReadAsJsonAsync<ProjectsDTO>();
            return message;
        }

        return null;
    }

    public async Task<List<ProjectsDTO>> GetProjects()
    {
        using var client = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(_host + ControllerAddress) };

        var response = await client.GetAsync(nameof(ProjectsController.GetProjects));

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var message = await response.Content.ReadAsJsonAsync<List<ProjectsDTO>>();
            return message;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

**ProjectFavoritesService**

```
public class ProjectFavoritesService : IProjectFavoritesService
{
    private readonly string _host;
    private const string ControllerAddress = "api/projectfavorites/";

    public ProjectFavoritesService(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        if (configuration == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(configuration)); }

        _host = configuration.GetSection("Data").GetSection("Host").Value;
    }

    public async Task AddFavorite(ProjectFavoritesDTO dto)
    {
        using var client = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(_host + ControllerAddress) };

        await client.PostAsJsonAsync(nameof(ProjectFavoritesController.AddFavorite), dto);
    }

    public async Task RemoveFavorite(ProjectFavoritesDTO dto)
    {
        using var client = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(_host + ControllerAddress) };

        await client.DeleteAsJsonAsync(nameof(ProjectFavoritesController.RemoveFavorite), dto);
    }

    public async Task<List<ProjectFavoritesDTO>> GetFavoritesByUser(string userId)
    {
        using var client = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(_host + ControllerAddress) };
        var response = await client.GetAsync($"{nameof(ProjectFavoritesController.GetFavoritesByUser)}?userId={userId}");

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var message = await response.Content.ReadAsJsonAsync<List<ProjectFavoritesDTO>>();
            return message;
        }

        return null;
    }

    public async Task<List<ProjectFavoritesDTO>> GetFavoritesByProject(int projectId)
    {
        using var client = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(_host + ControllerAddress) };

        var response = await client.GetAsync($"{nameof(ProjectFavoritesController.GetFavoritesByProject)}?projectId={projectId}");

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var message = await response.Content.ReadAsJsonAsync<List<ProjectFavoritesDTO>>();
            return message;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

### MVC

I'm using the standard mvc approach here instead of using razor pages, due to some limitations with the latter.

**DownloadsController**

```
public class DownloadsController : Controller
{
    private const int ItemsPerPage = 10;

    private readonly IMapper _mapper;
    private readonly IProjectsService _projectsService;
    private readonly IProjectFavoritesService _projectFavoritesService;
    private readonly UserManager<AspNetUsers> _userManager;

    private readonly PagingHandler _pagingHandler;

    public DownloadsController(
        IProjectsService projectsService,
        IProjectFavoritesService projectFavoritesService,
        UserManager<AspNetUsers> userManager,
        IMapper mapper)
    {
        _mapper = mapper;
        _projectsService = projectsService;
        _projectFavoritesService = projectFavoritesService;
        _userManager = userManager;
        _pagingHandler = new SearchHandler();
        _pagingHandler.SetNext(new SortHandler());
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Index(int pageNumber = 1)
    {
        TempData["currentPage"] = pageNumber;
        return View();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<JsonResult> GetProjects(PagingData data)
    {
        TempData["searchCriteria"] = data.SearchCriteria; //keep search after refresh in ui
        var currentUser = await GetCurrentUserAsync();
        var userFavorites = await _projectFavoritesService.GetFavoritesByUser(currentUser?.Id);
        var allProjects = (await _projectsService.GetProjects()).Select(p =>
        {
            var vm = _mapper.Map<ProjectsDTO, ProjectViewModel>(p);
            vm.IsFavorite = currentUser != null && userFavorites.Any(f => f.ProjectId == p.Id);

            return vm;
        });

        var projects = _pagingHandler.Handle(allProjects, data);

        var currentProjects = projects
            .Skip(ItemsPerPage * (data.CurrentPage - 1))
            .Take(ItemsPerPage);

        return Json(new
        {
            items = currentProjects,
            maxPages = GetMaxPages(projects),
        });
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult GetPartialProject(string json)
    {
        return PartialView("_ProjectPartial", JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ProjectViewModel>(json));
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult GetPartialNoResults()
    {
        return PartialView("_NoResultsPartial");
    }

    [Authorize(Policy = "User")]
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> SetFavoriteProject(int projectId)
    {
        var currentUser = await GetCurrentUserAsync();
        if (currentUser == null)
        {
            return Json(new {success = false});
        }

        await _projectFavoritesService.AddFavorite(new ProjectFavoritesDTO
            {UserId = currentUser.Id, ProjectId = projectId});

        return Json(new {success = true});
    }

    [Authorize(Policy = "User")]
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> RemoveFavoriteProject(int projectId)
    {
        var currentUser = await GetCurrentUserAsync();
        if (currentUser == null)
        {
            return Json(new {success = false});
        }

        await _projectFavoritesService.RemoveFavorite(new ProjectFavoritesDTO
            {UserId = currentUser.Id, ProjectId = projectId});

        return Json(new {success = true});
    }

    private int GetMaxPages(IEnumerable<ProjectViewModel> source)
    {
        return source == null ? 1 : (int) Math.Ceiling(source.Count() / (double) ItemsPerPage);
    }

    private Task<AspNetUsers> GetCurrentUserAsync() => _userManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User);
}
```

**Index.cshtml**

```
@inject SignInManager<AspNetUsers> SignInManager
@using Dex.Common.Resources
@using Dex.DataAccess.Models
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@{
    Layout = "_Layout";
    var searchCriteria = (string)TempData["searchCriteria"];
}

<br />

<div>
    <div class="float-left" style="margin-left: 45px;">
        <a id = "sortAsc" class="selected-arrow">
            <i class="fa fa-arrow-up"></i>
        </a>
        <a id = "sortDesc" class="unselected-arrow">
            <i class="fa fa-arrow-down"></i>
        </a>
        <div class="mainmenu">
            <ul id = "sortCategories" >
                < li >
                    < a href="#">
                        Sort
                        <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-down "></i>
                    </a>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href = "#" class="sort">Name</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href = "#" class="sort">Date</a>
                        </li>
                        @if(SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User))
{
                            < li >
                                < a href = "#" class="sort">Favorite</a>
                            </li>
                        }
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="float-right" style="margin-right: 45px;">
        <input id = "searchBar" class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search project" aria-label="Search" value="@searchCriteria">
    </div>

</div>

<br />
<br />

<div id = "projectsListDiv" class="box">
</div>

<div id = "paginationListDiv" class="text-center">
</div>

@section Scripts
{
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
        if (window.sessionStorage.getItem('currentPage') === null)
        {
            initializePagingVariables();
        }
        var maxPages = 1;

        refreshProjectsList();
        updateSortArrows();

            $('#searchBar').on('input',
                delay(function() {
            window.sessionStorage.setItem('searchCriteria', $('#searchBar').val());
            window.sessionStorage.setItem('currentPage', 1); //reset pages

            refreshProjectsList();
        },
                    100));

            $('#sortAsc').on('click',
                function() {
            window.sessionStorage.setItem('currentPage', 1); //reset pages
            window.sessionStorage.setItem('isAscending', true);

            refreshProjectsList();
            updateSortArrows();
        });

            $('#sortDesc').on('click',
                function() {
            window.sessionStorage.setItem('currentPage', 1); //reset pages
            window.sessionStorage.setItem('isAscending', false);

            refreshProjectsList();
            updateSortArrows();
        });

            $('#sortCategories').on('click', 'a.sort',
                function() {
            window.sessionStorage.setItem('sort', $(this).text());
            refreshProjectsList();
        });

            $('#paginationListDiv').on('click', 'a.page-navigator',
                function() {
            var element = $(this);
            var currentPage = parseInt(window.sessionStorage.getItem('currentPage'));
            if (currentPage > 1 && element.attr('id') == 'previousPage')
            {
                window.sessionStorage.setItem('currentPage', currentPage - 1);
            }
            else if (currentPage < maxPages && element.attr('id') == 'nextPage')
            {
                window.sessionStorage.setItem('currentPage', currentPage + 1);
            }
            else if (element.attr('id').indexOf('page') >= 0)
            {
                window.sessionStorage.setItem('currentPage', element.attr('id').substring('page'.length));
            }

            refreshProjectsList();
        });

        function refreshProjectsList()
        {
            var request = getProjectsAjax();
            loadProjectsFromAjax(request);
        }

        function getProjectsAjax()
        {
            return $.ajax({
            url: '/Downloads/GetProjects',
                    method: 'GET',
                    accepts: 'text/json',
                    data:
                {
                currentPage: window.sessionStorage.getItem('currentPage'),
                        searchCriteria: window.sessionStorage.getItem('searchCriteria'),
                        sort: window.sessionStorage.getItem('sort'),
                        isAscending: window.sessionStorage.getItem('isAscending')
                    },
                    headers:
                {
                RequestVerificationToken:
                            $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val()
                    }
            });
    }

    function ajaxFavorite(resourceName, projectId) {
        return $.ajax({
        url: '/Downloads/' + resourceName,
                    method: 'GET',
                    accepts: 'text/json',
                    data:
            {
            projectId: projectId
                    },
                    headers:
            {
            RequestVerificationToken:
                            $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val()
                    }
        });
    }

    function loadProjectsFromAjax(ajaxRequest) {
        ajaxRequest.done(function(data) {
            if (data.items.length > 0)
            {
                appendProjectItems(data.items);
                appendPaginationItems(window.sessionStorage.getItem('currentPage'), data.maxPages);
            }
            else
            {
                loadNoResultView();
            }
        });
    }

    document.addEventListener('click',
                function (e) {
        if (hasClass(e.target, 'favoriteStar'))
        {
            var resourceName = 'RemoveFavoriteProject';
            if (hasClass(e.target, 'unchecked'))
            {
                resourceName = 'SetFavoriteProject';
            }

            var classes = e.target.className.split(' ');
            var projectId = 0;
            var classPrefix = 'project-';
            for (var i = 0; i < classes.length; i++)
            {
                if (classes[i].indexOf(classPrefix) >= 0)
                {
                    projectId = classes[i].substring(classPrefix.length);
                    break;
                }
            }

            var request = ajaxFavorite(resourceName, projectId);
            request.fail(function(jqXHR) {
                if (jqXHR.status === 401)
                {
                                $.growl.warning({ message: 'You need to be logged in to set favorites ' });
                }
            });

            request.done(function(data) {
                if (data.success)
                {
                    flipStarClasses(e.target);
                }
            });
        }
    }, false);

    function appendProjectItems(data) {
        var list = $('<ul id="projectsList" class="text-center p-0">');
                $('#projectsListDiv').html(list);

        var promises = data.map(function(e) {
            return new Promise(function(resolve) {
                        $.get('/Downloads/GetPartialProject',
                            { json: JSON.stringify(e) },
                            function (response) {
                                var htmlElement = '<li class="horizontal-li box faded-out">' + response + '</li>';
            resolve(htmlElement);
        });
    });
});

                Promise.all(promises).then(function (promiseResults) {
                    $('#projectsList').append(promiseResults);
});

                list.append('</ul>');
                window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('projectsList')).opacity; //forces batch
            }

            function appendPaginationItems(currentPage, totalPages)
{
    maxPages = totalPages;
    var list = $('<ul id="paginationListDiv" class="pagination">');
    list.append(
        '<li><a href="#" id="previousPage" class="box faded-out page-navigator">«</a></li>');
                $('#paginationListDiv').html(list);
    for (var i = 1; i <= maxPages; i++)
    {
        if (currentPage == i)
        {
            list.append('<li><a href="#" id="page' +
                i +
                '" class="active box faded-out page-navigator"</a>' +
                i +
                '</li>');
        }
        else
        {
            list.append('<li><a href="#" id="page' +
                i +
                '"class="box faded-out page-navigator" </a>' +
                i +
                '</li>');
        }
    }
    list.append(
        '<li><a href="#" id="nextPage" class="box faded-out page-navigator">»</a></li>');
    list.append('</ul>');
}

function updateSortArrows()
{
    if (window.sessionStorage.getItem('isAscending') === 'true')
    {
                    $('#sortAsc').removeClass('unselected-arrow');
                    $('#sortAsc').addClass('selected-arrow');
                    $('#sortDesc').removeClass('selected-arrow');
                    $('#sortDesc').addClass('unselected-arrow');
    }
    else
    {
                    $('#sortDesc').removeClass('unselected-arrow');
                    $('#sortDesc').addClass('selected-arrow');
                    $('#sortAsc').removeClass('selected-arrow');
                    $('#sortAsc').addClass('unselected-arrow');
    }
}

function loadNoResultView()
{
                $.get('/Downloads/GetPartialNoResults',
                    function(response) {
                        $('#projectsListDiv').html(response);
                        $('#paginationListDiv').html('');
    });
}

function initializePagingVariables()
{
    window.sessionStorage.setItem('searchCriteria', $('#searchBar').val());
    window.sessionStorage.setItem('currentPage', 1);
    window.sessionStorage.setItem('sort', 'name');
    window.sessionStorage.setItem('isAscending', true);
}

function flipStarClasses(e)
{
    if (hasClass(e, 'checked'))
    {
        e.classList.remove("checked");
        e.classList.remove("bounceIn");
        e.classList.add("unchecked");
    }
    else
    {
        e.classList.remove("unchecked");
        e.classList.add("checked");
        e.classList.add("bounceIn");
    }
}
        });
    </script>
}
```

To allow for an easier paging in the controller, there are a couple helper classes, implemented using a slightly modified chain of responsibility:

```
public interface IHandler<T>
{
    IHandler<T> SetNext(IHandler<T> handler);

    T Handle(T request, object additionalData);
}

public abstract class PagingHandler : IHandler<IEnumerable<ProjectViewModel>>
{
    private IHandler<IEnumerable<ProjectViewModel>> _nextHandler;

    public IHandler<IEnumerable<ProjectViewModel>> SetNext(
        IHandler<IEnumerable<ProjectViewModel>> handler)
    {
        this._nextHandler = handler;
        return handler;
    }

    public virtual IEnumerable<ProjectViewModel> Handle(IEnumerable<ProjectViewModel> request,
        object additionalData)
    {
        if (_nextHandler == null)
        {
            return request;
        }

        return _nextHandler.Handle(request, additionalData);
    }
}

public class SearchHandler : PagingHandler
{
    public override IEnumerable<ProjectViewModel> Handle(IEnumerable<ProjectViewModel> request,
        object additionalData)
    {
        if (additionalData is PagingData pagingData && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(pagingData.SearchCriteria))
        {
            return base.Handle(
                request.Where(p =>
                    p.ProjectName.Contains(pagingData.SearchCriteria, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)),
                additionalData);
        }

        return base.Handle(request, additionalData);
    }
}

public class SortHandler : PagingHandler
{
    public override IEnumerable<ProjectViewModel> Handle(IEnumerable<ProjectViewModel> request,
        object additionalData)
    {
        if (additionalData is PagingData pagingData && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(pagingData.Sort))
        {
            return base.Handle(
                ProjectSortResolver.Resolve(pagingData.Sort).Sort(request, pagingData.IsAscending),
                additionalData);
        }

        return base.Handle(request, additionalData);
    }
}

public static class ProjectSortResolver
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<string, ISortStrategy<ProjectViewModel>> _sortStrategies;

    static ProjectSortResolver()
    {
        _sortStrategies =
            new Dictionary<string, ISortStrategy<ProjectViewModel>>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
            {
                ["name"] = new ProjectNameSortStrategy(),
                ["date"] = new ProjectDateSortStrategy(),
                ["favorite"] = new ProjectFavoriteSortStrategy(),

            };
    }

    public static ISortStrategy<ProjectViewModel> Resolve(string type)
    {
        return _sortStrategies.TryGetValue(type, out var strategy) ? strategy : null;
    }
}

public interface ISortStrategy<T>
{
    IEnumerable<T> Sort(IEnumerable<T> data, bool isAscending);
}

public class ProjectNameSortStrategy : ISortStrategy<ProjectViewModel>
{
    public IEnumerable<ProjectViewModel> Sort(IEnumerable<ProjectViewModel> data, bool isAscending)
    {
        if (isAscending)
        {
            return data.OrderBy(p => p.ProjectName);
        }

        return data.OrderByDescending(p => p.ProjectName);
    }
}

public class ProjectDateSortStrategy : ISortStrategy<ProjectViewModel>
{
    public IEnumerable<ProjectViewModel> Sort(IEnumerable<ProjectViewModel> data, bool isAscending)
    {
        if (isAscending)
        {
            return data.OrderBy(p => p.ProjectDate);
        }

        return data.OrderByDescending(p => p.ProjectDate);
    }
}

public class ProjectFavoriteSortStrategy : ISortStrategy<ProjectViewModel>
{
    public IEnumerable<ProjectViewModel> Sort(IEnumerable<ProjectViewModel> data, bool isAscending)
    {
        if (isAscending)
        {
            return data.OrderBy(p => p.IsFavorite);
        }

        return data.OrderByDescending(p => p.IsFavorite);
    }
}

public class PagingData
{
    public int CurrentPage { get; set; }
    public string SearchCriteria { get; set; }
    public string Sort { get; set; }
    public bool IsAscending { get; set; }
}
```

I'm primarily looking for reviews focusing on the overall design of the functionality, but anything else is also welcome!

Comment: `AddProject, ModifyProject, RemoveProject, GetProject` I think it would be better if you just use `Add, Modify, Remove, Get` since its under Project, there is no need to repeat it in each method. same goes for API. Also, `GetProject(int id)` and `GetProjects()`, just use `Get()` and `Get(int Id)`, so when I call `api/projects` it'll return all projects, and if i call `api/projects/10` it'll return project number 10 and so on. Also, `ProjectFavoritesService` is part of `ProjectService` those, in the API it seems to be reasonable to do `api/projects/favorites`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Injecting `IConfiguration` is more and more being seen as an indicator of Single Responsibility Principle (SRP) violation when the framework allows for a more SOLID approach of dealing with configuration at the composition root.

Also the creation of new `HttpClient` manually can cause issues

#### Reference [You're using HttpClient wrong](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/)

Both API service implementations have done this. Both implementations only need the client injected so it should be configured to do so

*ConfigureServices*

```
var host = Configuration.GetSection("Data").GetSection("Host").Value;
projectsControllerBaseAddress = new Uri(host + "api/projects/");
projectsFavoritesControllerBaseAddress = new Uri(host + "api/projectfavorites/");

//Register Typed clients
services.AddHttpClient<IProjectsService, ProjectService>(client => {
    client.BaseAddress = projectsControllerBaseAddress;
    
    //...any other settings needed
});

services.AddHttpClient<IProjectFavoritesService, ProjectFavoritesService>(client => {
    client.BaseAddress = projectsFavoritesControllerBaseAddress;
    
    //...any other settings needed
})
```

Reference [How to use Typed Clients with HttpClientFactory](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests#how-to-use-typed-clients-with-httpclientfactory)

This removes the need for creating the clients within the services as it will be injected by the framework that will also manage its lifetime.

`ProjectService` Refactored:

```
public class ProjectsService : IProjectsService {
    private readonly HttpClient client;

    public ProjectsService(HttpClient client) {
        if (client == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(client)); }
        this.client = client;
    }

    public async Task<int> AddProject(ProjectsDTO dto) {
        var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(nameof(ProjectsController.AddProject), dto);
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode) {
            var message = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            if (int.TryParse(message, out var id)) {
                return id;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public async Task<int> ModifyProject(ProjectsDTO dto) {
        var response = await client.PutAsJsonAsync(nameof(ProjectsController.ModifyProject), dto);
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode) {
            var message = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            if (int.TryParse(message, out var id)) {
                return id;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public async Task RemoveProject(int id) {
        await client.DeleteAsync($"{nameof(ProjectsController.RemoveProject)}?id={id}");
    }

    public async Task<ProjectsDTO> GetProject(int id) {
        var response = await client.GetAsync($"{nameof(ProjectsController.GetProject)}?id={id}");
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode) {
            var message = await response.Content.ReadAsJsonAsync<ProjectsDTO>();
            return message;
        }
        return null; //Should consider NullObject pattern
    }

    public async Task<List<ProjectsDTO>> GetProjects() {
        var response = await client.GetAsync(nameof(ProjectsController.GetProjects));
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode) {
            var message = await response.Content.ReadAsJsonAsync<List<ProjectsDTO>>();
            return message;
        }
        return new List<ProjectsDTO>(); //Return empty list to avoid null errors.
    }
}
```

`ProjectFavoritesService` Refactored

```
public class ProjectFavoritesService : IProjectFavoritesService {
    private readonly HttpClient client;
    
    public ProjectFavoritesService(IConfiguration configuration) {
        if (configuration == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(configuration)); }
        this.client = client;
    }

    public async Task AddFavorite(ProjectFavoritesDTO dto) {
        await client.PostAsJsonAsync(nameof(ProjectFavoritesController.AddFavorite), dto);
    }

    public async Task RemoveFavorite(ProjectFavoritesDTO dto) {
        await client.DeleteAsJsonAsync(nameof(ProjectFavoritesController.RemoveFavorite), dto);
    }

    public async Task<List<ProjectFavoritesDTO>> GetFavoritesByUser(string userId) {
        var response = await client.GetAsync($"{nameof(ProjectFavoritesController.GetFavoritesByUser)}?userId={userId}");
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode) {
            var message = await response.Content.ReadAsJsonAsync<List<ProjectFavoritesDTO>>();
            return message;
        }
        return List<ProjectFavoritesDTO>();
    }

    public async Task<List<ProjectFavoritesDTO>> GetFavoritesByProject(int projectId) {
        var response = await client.GetAsync($"{nameof(ProjectFavoritesController.GetFavoritesByProject)}?projectId={projectId}");
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode) {
            var message = await response.Content.ReadAsJsonAsync<List<ProjectFavoritesDTO>>();
            return message;
        }
        return new List<ProjectFavoritesDTO>();
    }
}
```

Your service functions returning lists should return an empty list to avoid null errors and you should also consider using Null Object Pattern for functions returning reference types.

Comment: Also, another good `HttpClient` reference: https://josefottosson.se/you-are-probably-still-using-httpclient-wrong-and-it-is-destabilizing-your-software/

Comment: I wasn't feeling comfortable with the way the http client was handled either, this solves it! Great points!

Comment: It's also a great solution because it's consistent with the rest of the code, I also configure and inject the dbcontext in the same way, I don't know why I didn't thought of that :)

Answer (score 2):

Returning early if a specific condition is met will make a method more readable because the level of indentation is decreased. E.g in `ProjectsController.AddProject(ProjectsDTO)` you could revert the `if` condition at the top of the method like so

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid) { return BadRequest(); }
```

and because you return `BadRequest()` in case of an exception you could have an empty `catch` block but adding a `finally` to return `BadRequest()` for the case that an exception is thrown **and** for `entity.Id <= 0`.

This would look like so

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("AddProject")]
public IActionResult AddProject(ProjectsDTO dto)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid) { return BadRequest(); }

    try
    {
        var entity = _mapper.Map<Projects>(dto);
        _context.Projects.Add(entity);
        _context.SaveChanges();

        if (entity.Id > 0)
        {
            return Ok(entity.Id);
        }
    }
    catch {} // swallowing exception, but returning BadRequest()

    return BadRequest();
}
```

This pattern should be used in `ProjectsController.ModifyProject()` and `ProjectFavoritesController.AddFavorite()` as well.

I find it a little bit odd that you need to check if `_context == null` in `ProjectsController.GetProjects()` but for each other method you don't check the state of that field. IMO you should validate this inside the constructor and throwing an `ArgumentNullException` if the passed `context` is null.
This applies for `ProjectFavoritesController` as well.

In both `AddProject()` and `ModifyProject` you don't validate the method argument. Its a `public` method hence you really should do it. This applies for `AddFavorite()` of the `ProjectFavoritesController` as well.

In `ProjectFavoritesController.GetFavoritesByUser()` you check if the passed in `userId` is null, but what about an empty string ?

Comment: Consistency and code style are important factors for me, thank you for the suggestions!

Comment: Just one thing, finally blocks cannot return value in C#.

Comment: Wow, good catch. Updated answer.